# Group records based on another collection with date range relation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**SCENARIO:**

I have a collection to save **sessionLogs** with some properties like:

- userId
- deviceType
- startDate
- endDate

And I have another collection for **actionLogs**:

- userId
- deviceType
- createdAt
- action

I can't have the reference of the sessionLog on the actionLogs, or add the actionLogs on a subcollection in sessionLog records... This is because the nature of the application. (I think it's not necessary to explain this for the current question)

**PROBLEM:**

I need to get the **LIST** of sessionLogs that had a specific actionLog. (and another filters, like date, user, etc...)

How would I achieve a result like that with only query executions?

I think the group should be using the date period (startDate, endDate), userId and deviceType.

Example:

Session Log

- userId: x | deviceType: ios | startDate: 2018-3-21 | endDate 2018-3-22

Action Logs related to that SessionLog

- userId: x | deviceType: ios | date: 2018-3-21 | Action: X
- userId: x | deviceType: ios | date: 2018-3-22 | Action: Y

Comment: can you please paste a sample of 2 documents for each collection? Is startDate and endDate a Date object or string type?

Comment: I'm not on my dev environment to copy and paste samples right now, sorry. But date properties are Date Objects, not strings.

Comment: that's okay. If I undesrstood it well, it should be something like this? https://gist.github.com/felipsmartins/09b5b85e1bf1e9615a8772cd172e6f71

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if I understand it well, it would be achieved by using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) (optional) stages.
As lookup has "merged/joined" the collections for us so you can query any criteria via [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage and group via [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage of [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/):

We consider the following collections:

```
var sessionsLog = [
    {

        'userId': "132",
        'deviceType': "ios",
        'startDate': ISODate('2018-02-23'),
        'endDate': ISODate('2018-02-28')
    },
    {

        'userId': "789",
        'deviceType': "android",
        'startDate': ISODate('2018-02-15'),
        'endDate': ISODate('2018-02-19')
    },
    {

        'userId': "225",
        'deviceType': "ios",
        'startDate': ISODate('2018-03-01'),
        'endDate': ISODate('2018-03-17')
    }
];

var actionsLog = [
    {

        'userId': '225',
        'deviceType': 'ios',
        'createdAt': ISODate('2018-03-03'),
        'action': 'X'
    },
    {

        'userId': '789',
        'deviceType': 'android',
        'createdAt': ISODate('2018-02-16'),
        'action': 'Y'
    },
    {

        'userId': '789',
        'deviceType': 'android',
        'createdAt': ISODate('2018-02-16'),
        'action': 'Z'
    }
];

db.actionLogs.insert(actionsLog); //via mongo shell...
db.sessionLogs.insert(sessionsLog); //via mongo sheell...
```

## Step 1: Join collections

It is when [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator comes in handy. Here we gonna join the collections by `userId` field but it is up to you "wire" collections by field what you want!

```
db.sessionLogs.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'actionLogs',
            foreignField: 'userId',
            localField: 'userId',
            as: 'action_log'
        }
    }  
])
```

## Step 2: Filter the docs

> I need to get the LIST of sessionLogs that had a specific actionLog.
>   (and another filters, like date, user, etc...)

Once we have the collections joined it should be easy to fetch/filter documents by specific criteria using [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator.
But before it I think adding [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage right before [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match) stage  does make the job a bit easier (but is is not required at all), so it would be:

```
db.sessionLogs.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'actionLogs',
            foreignField: 'userId',
            localField: 'userId',
            as: 'action_log'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$action_logs'
    }  
])
```

And it returns:

```
  {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ab463233a856b4829f5e75d"),
        "userId": "789",
        "deviceType": "android",
        "startDate": ISODate("2018-02-15T00:00:00Z"),
        "endDate": ISODate("2018-02-19T00:00:00Z"),
        "action_log": {
            "_id": ObjectId("5ab463363a856b4829f5e760"),
            "userId": "789",
            "deviceType": "android",
            "createdAt": ISODate("2018-02-16T00:00:00Z"),
            "action": "Y"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ab463233a856b4829f5e75d"),
        "userId": "789",
        "deviceType": "android",
        "startDate": ISODate("2018-02-15T00:00:00Z"),
        "endDate": ISODate("2018-02-19T00:00:00Z"),
        "action_log": {
            "_id": ObjectId("5ab463363a856b4829f5e761"),
            "userId": "789",
            "deviceType": "android",
            "createdAt": ISODate("2018-02-16T00:00:00Z"),
            "action": "Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ab463233a856b4829f5e75e"),
        "userId": "225",
        "deviceType": "ios",
        "startDate": ISODate("2018-03-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "endDate": ISODate("2018-03-17T00:00:00Z"),
        "action_log": {
            "_id": ObjectId("5ab463363a856b4829f5e75f"),
            "userId": "225",
            "deviceType": "ios",
            "createdAt": ISODate("2018-03-03T00:00:00Z"),
            "action": "X"
        }
    }
```

Now we can filter docs like this (where action is equals to X):

```
db.sessionLogs.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'actionLogs',
            foreignField: 'userId',
            localField: 'userId',
            as: 'action_log'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$action_log'
    },
    {
        $match: {'action_log.action': 'X' }
    }

])
```

In the same way, grouping by adding the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage for aggregation pipeline should be pretty easy!

**SIDE NOTES:**

> - [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) are available only mongodb 3.2+
> - Be aware adding a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage in [pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) works like a left outer join.
> - Don't take the above examples as a "rule", it's just a guideline and you'll most likely   make changes for your requirements.